# Cannot use Virtualbox 6.1 in Fedora 36 Silveblue

Tags: permissions, fedora, filesystems, virtualbox

I successfully installed VirtualBox 6.1 in my Fedora 36 Silverblue according these guidelines...

[Guidelines_installation_VirtualBox6.1_Fedora_36_Silverblue](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-virtualbox-on-fedora-linux/)

It works, however:

1. I cannot add my `$USER` to the
   `vboxusers` group.
2. I cannot install the `VirtualBox Extension Pack`.

Basically my VirtualBox is installed in `/usr/lib/virtualbox` and this is a `read-only filesystem`. I cannot change permissions with `chmod` or `chown`.

The error I get when trying to install the `Extension Pack` is:

`Failed to install the Extension Pack /var/home/x/x/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.36a-152435.vbox-extpack.`

`The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp: error: Failed to set directory permissions on '/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks': VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND rcExit=1.`

And second problem why I cannot add `$USER`to `vboxusers`, I have no clue.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: If `/usr/lib`, or `/usr`, or `/`, is read-only, then you are going to have to remount it read-write, install, and if necessary, remount it read-only. As for not adding your user to the group, you'll have to give us some idea why, an error or something. You should check `/etc/group` whether it has that entry.

Comment: Fedora SilverBlue is not suitable for installing VBox at all.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - why not? It seems to work apart from above little obstacles.

Comment: Silverblue is a special version of Fedora that is not intended to have  normal packages like Virtualbox added. The guide you have linked to is for regular Fedora. I believe you can add flatpaks to silverblue but nothing else.

Comment: https://silverblue.fedoraproject.org/about it feels to me VBox and Fedora SilverBlue are kinda incompatible